# convert boolean formula to DNF

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

This is the given formula:

```
¬(¬(d -> a) ∧ (¬a -> b ∧ b))
```

Here's what I did so far:

```
1. ¬(¬(¬d ∨ a) ∧ (a ∨ b ∧ b))
2. ¬((d ∧ ¬a) ∧ (a ∨ b))
3. (¬d ∨ a) ∨ (!a ∧ !b)
```

How can I proceed from step 3 to get the DNF?

Comment: In second one, should it be (!a ->b) & b ? Because b & b same as just b.

Comment: No, it is (!a -> b & b)

Comment: Well if & has higher priority than -> tthen the b&b can be replaced by just b.

Comment: Yeah, I did that in the second step.

Comment: You already have disjunctive normal form (DNF). `(¬d )∨ (a) ∨ (\lnot a ∧ \lnot b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is fine, and it is in DNF form, which  we can see by using parentheses to better show each of the disjuncts:

$$(¬d \lor a) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b) $$ $$\equiv (\lnot d) \lor (a) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b)\tag{DNF}$$
$$\equiv \lnot d \lor (a \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b))$$  $$\equiv \lnot d \lor (\underbrace{(a\lor \lnot a)}_{\large\text{True}}\land (a \lor \lnot b))\tag{distrubution}$$
$$\equiv \lnot d \lor (\text{True} \land (a \lor \lnot b))$$

$$\equiv \lnot d \lor  a\lor \lnot b\tag{DNF}$$

That is, we've arrived at the disjuntive normal form of you original proposition.  DNF is a disjunction (or'ing) of terms that are:

- literals, including negated literals, and/or
- conjuctions of literals and/or negated literals, as we see in the $(\lnot a \land \lnot b)$ term above.
- Also, for developing "full DNF form" one needs to try to arrive at a DNF with each variable appearing only once in one disjunct.

Comment: I had a typo in my question. Sorry. The first expression is !(d->a). I updated my question.

Comment: The solution given for this question is: !b&d | !d | a&b&d

Comment: Please double-check the answer for this question.  If you've already double-checked the solution associated with this question, then there is likely a typo in the printing, and/or the solution to another question was mis-identified.  I am quite certain your work, and my own, is correct.  (I even tried to regroup the second part of the original proposition, i.e. as $( (¬a \to  b) ∧ b) = ((a \lor b) \land b)$ and proceeded to arrive at the same answer given above.

Comment: Umm, does it have to do anything with variable ordering?

Comment: The solution you posted is not simplified: We can reduce it (distributive properties) to $$(\lnot b \land d) \lor (a \land d) \lor \lnot d$$  If $\lnot d$ is true, we're done. Otherwise, we have, by default $\lnot(\lnot d) \equiv d$.  $d$ holds, by default, whenever $\lnot d$ fails to hold.  And in that case, given $d$, we need $\lnot b \lor a$.  That is, we arrive at $\lnot b \lor  a \lor \lnot d$.